# How to display unicode in MySQL result?

Tags: mysql, unicode

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82f65/1

I tried this:

```
create table x(y varchar(100) character set utf8);

insert into x(y) values('爱');
```

But the chinese character doesn't appear:

```
select y from x;
```

Output:

```
Y
?
```

Comment: Can check out my answer. In fiddle it is not displaying but in mysql it working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of sqlfiddle.com.  The problem was that I didn't have my connection string and default database encoding for mysql setup to properly handle UTF8.  I have fixed this now, but because the fiddle you posted is still using the obsolete settings, you'll have to see it working here on my slightly-modified version of your fiddle:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e79e8/1

Your link might start working eventually, it just needs to clear out of the running memory and be reset.  After no one hits it for a while it should be harvested and then ready to be built back up cleanly.  Thanks!

FYI, the changes I had to make to get it to work were found here: http://www.compoundtheory.com/?action=displayPost&ID=421

The relavent bits where adding this to my connection string from java: 
`useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

And adding this to my create database statement:

`create database my_new_database default CHARACTER SET = utf8 default COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: If there would be http://nosqlfiddle.com I'm counting on you on being able to deliver it as beautifully as http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: (I landed on this thread searching for something else.) Having recently discovered sqlfiddle, I have to say .. incredibly awesome job there Jake!

Comment: Thanks @leigh! It might not surprise you to learn that I wrote it in CF, lol. Good times.

Comment: Well it is fantastic! It is my new favorite tool :)

Answer (score 2):

It is working fine in mysql on my localhost. it may be due to  mysql charset or some setting please check it.
If you have to run this query via program like php  then

run query before select query

```
"SET NAMES utf8"
```

It will be return result properly
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Chinese character is not displaying in fiddle but in actual mysql database it is working fine. Kindly check your mysql version

[image: Result of your select Statment]